# Alchemy api usage in python

Tags: python, api, entities, alchemy

I am using Alchemy API for named entity extraction. For this, I am using Python library given by alchemy. I am able to get the results in XML, but I am not able to figure out how to get the results in JSON. Running the following code, I could get the entities in XML.

entities = alchemyObj.HTMLGetRankedNamedEntities(htmlFile, htmlFile);
print entities

How to set the output mode to JSON in the above code.

Comment: what happens if you specify `outputMode='json'` argument?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thanks for the reply. I have tried giving that, but it dindn't work. I could tweak the API library and could the results now in 'json'.